# Bullet Physics too many rigid bodies framerate drops

Tags: c++, bullet-physics

I have a question regarding rigid bodies in bullet physics.

At the moment I have low-poly asteroids, which I create a convex Hull shape.
Then I add a motion state and give them a linear velocity.

Collision and everything is working fine, if its a low amount of asteroids (less than 5).

But as soon as the amound of objects in the world get higher, my framerate starts to drop under 1 FPS.

I have a Intel i56600k and a AMD Fury. Could it be related to my hardware? 
Or is bullet limited in this regard? Or did I do something wrong in my program?

I'm writing the game in C++.

Comment: What is the count of objects?

Comment: I just found the problem. Apparently the debug drawer is costing me all the performance, if i turn it off, i can easily handle more than 1000 Objects without dropping to less than 200 FPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the Debug Drawer i was using was responsible for the performance Issues.

When it is turned off, everything is working as expected.